# xpath contains() not working: returning every node that contains text i.e. where text is not null

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I am parsing a large xml file containing biological data.

The xml file is organised like this:

```
<part>
    <part_id>41926</part_id>
    <part_name>BBa_K1906018</part_name>
    <part_short_name>K1906018</part_short_name>
    <part_short_desc>Ribothermometer JB1-G3</part_short_desc>
    <part_type>RBS</part_type>
    <release_status>Not Released</release_status>
    <sample_status>Not in stock</sample_status>
    <part_results>None</part_results>
    <part_nickname/>
    <part_rating/>
    <part_url>http://parts.igem.org/Part:BBa_K1906018</part_url>
    <part_entered>2016-10-14</part_entered>
    <part_author>Yuwei Han</part_author>
    <deep_subparts/>
    <specified_subparts/>
    <specified_subscars/>
    <sequences>
        <seq_data>tactagagctcttattgtaaaacatgtactaaggagtactag </seq_data>
    </sequences>
...
</part>
```

I have already developed xpath expressions that return exact matches E.g.

```
current_tree.xpath("//part/%s/text()[normalize-space(.)='%s']/../.."
                   "" % (arg_key, arg_values[0]))
```

Where arg_key will refer to one of the nodes of the document e.g. "part_type" and arg_values[0] will refer to an argument value such as "RBS".

I am trying to write an xpath expression that will find all seq_data nodes that contain a sequence motif, and return the nearest part parent node.

My xpath expression to do this (not working):

```
current_tree.xpath("//seq_data/text()[contains(.,%s)]"
                   "/ancestor::part" % (arg_values[0]))
```

This returns all parts whose seq_data node contains any text at all, i.e. it's fetching all nodes whose seq_data/text() is not empty.

I can't figure out why. Thanks

Comment: Try `contains(.,'%s')`. Note the single quotes around `%s`, which make the argument being interpreted as string.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, works perfectly, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: To elaborate, `contains(., banana)` means `contains(., child::banana)` and if there are no child `banana` elements, converting the empty node-set to a string produces a zero-length string, and `contains(X, '')` is always true because every string contains a zero-length string as a substring.